# MoveIt End Effector positioning

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

My question is that how can I move the end-effector forward. (Say, go forward by 0.05 m on Y-axis)?

My current status is the following:

I made my robot to move to a given position using rviz, so the robot position is not in the "center".
After this I want to make the end effector to move by 0.05 m forward on Y-axis (**as if i would like to push a button with my finger:)** )

```
  geometry_msgs::Pose target_pose1 = group.getCurrentPose().pose;
  target_pose1.position.y -= 0.05;
  group.setPoseTarget(target_pose1);
  success = group.plan(my_plan);
  if (success) {
     group.execute(my_plan);
  }
```

But this does not work, because `target_pose1.position.y -= 0.05;` refers to the world coordinates not to the end-effector coordinates.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228190/moveit-end-effector-positioning/) by [Joska213](https://answers.ros.org/users/26025/joska213/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2016-03-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solution was:

```
const Eigen::Affine3d &end_effector_state = kinematic_state->getGlobalLinkTransform("eef_link");
geometry_msgs::Pose pose;
tf::poseEigenToMsg(end_effector_state, pose);
pose.position.y -= 0.05;
group.setPoseTarget(pose);
```

---

Originally posted by [Joska213](https://answers.ros.org/users/26025/joska213/) with karma: 36 on 2016-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arowana](https://answers.ros.org/users/22294/arowana/) on 2016-03-08**:
What happen if you take a empty geometry_msgs::PoseStamped, use identity quaternion as orientation. Then add your translation, frame_id should be your end effector. It looks cleaner to me.

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2020-05-18**:
Then you will constrain your end effector to that neutral orientation, which is not generally what you want. For many robot arms in their default configuration, a neutral orientation in their base coordinate system means pointing upwards.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Old post, but it is easier to work with `PoseStamped` objects. Both MoveIt and TF support them natively, and you can transform easily to the frame in which you want to apply the offset:

```
tf::TransformListener tf_listener; // Declared in advance

...

geometry_msgs::PoseStamped pose = group.getCurrentPose();
geometry_msgs::PoseStamped pose_in_ee_frame;
tf_listener.transformPose("your_end_effector_frame", pose, pose_in_ee_frame);
pose_in_ee_frame.pose.position.y -= .05;
group.setPoseTarget(pose_in_ee_frame);

...
```

---

Originally posted by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) with karma: 2180 on 2020-05-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nihalar](https://answers.ros.org/users/54529/nihalar/) on 2020-05-20**:
Do you know how to do this using tf2?